# How to create form using foreign keys and inlines

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am just trying to make an polling app and just want to have a simple HTML page where I can have `poll_text` and 3/4 `choice_text` fields.

currently my models looks like following

```
#models.py
class Poll(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True
    )
    poll_text = models.CharField((""), max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.poll_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = '')
    choice_text = models.CharField( max_length=200)
    no_of_votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

and this is how my `forms.py` looks like.

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Poll, Choice

class CreatePollForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ('poll_text',)
```

and finally the `admin.py`, looks like this, this gives me correct presentation in localhost/admin, and that presentation I want in a HTML page.

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Poll, Choice
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Register your models here.

class ChoiceInLine(admin.TabularInline): 
    model = Choice 
    extra = 5


class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': ('user','poll_text',)})]
    inlines = [ChoiceInLine]
```

please guide me what changes needs to be made, also please suggest how can i tweak my model to have a record of that an user has voted this poll.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a html,urls and views file. It should look like this.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for i in list%}
           {{i.poll}}
           {{i.choice_text}}
        {% endfor%}
    </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 
def index(request):
    list=Choice.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'list': list})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',app.views.index,name='index'),   #here you should change to the name off your current app
   ]
```

I could have maybe some typing errors, but it should something like this.

Comment: I am not sure, if you get the question.  I want to have an HTML which ll give you field to add a poll_text and some choices. and these choices should be linked with Poll in backend.

Comment: so you have to do some research you cannot ask people for the whole code. And if they trying to help you should thank them that they are helping you and not blaming for it. Have nice time with your project which I am sure you can figure everything alone out.